# logs on second run of an ios application in the simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I have a question which seems like it should be a fairly common occurrence. I am trying to test code which only runs the first time an ios application is installed. While in principle this is very easy, I'm having trouble with it behaving properly the second time the app runs (note, this is *not* crash related).

I have been force running the app for a second time using the "Application does not run in background" flag in the plist, and then just hitting the home button. This works great, except i stop getting log data after the first run.

Does anyone know how to test for this situation in a way where you can continue seeing the log information after the app closes? For example, if there is a way to attach the xcode logger to the new process id? Or just another way to force an app reboot without losing the logging feature?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In `Organizer` under `Devices` you should be able to view the logs in the `Console`.

Comment: I think this only works for a physical device right? I am in the simulator and don't see anything there? I *could* do it with a device I guess, but it would be nice if this would work in the simulator?

Comment: Yeah, this will only work on a device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the debugger menu:

```
Product>Attach To Process
```

(Results may vary with different versions of Xcode).

Also, you might need to insert a sleep at the very start of your launch to catch the very early log messages.

**EDIT:** If you're on a device then you can use the *Device Organizer* (cmd+shift+2) to watch all logs on a device.